# How to search a Doctrine NestedSet?

Tags: search, doctrine, nested-sets

How can i searching in nested set, and recover the filtered data in tree structure?

example:
root
 |
cat1:

- subcat1
- subcat2
- subcat3
  cat2:
- subcateg1
- subc2

I search the 'subc2'.
root
 |
cat2:

- subc2

This is my fixtures for the test table:

```
FokonyviKategoria:
  fok0:
    megnevezes: Főkönyvi kategóriák
    children:
      fok1:
        megnevezes: Főkönyvi teszt 1
      fok2:
        megnevezes: Főkönyvi teszt 2
      fok3:
        megnevezes: Főkönyvi teszt 3
        children:
          fok4:
            megnevezes: Főkönyvi teszt 4
          fok5:
            megnevezes: Főkönyvi teszt 5
```

And the table definition:

```
FokonyviKategoria:
  actAs:
    NestedSet:
      hasManyRoots: false
  columns:
    megnevezes: string(255)
  relations:
    Szamlak:
      type: many
      local: id
      foreign: fokonyvi_kategoria_id
      foreignAlias: FokonyviKategoria
```

And this my attempt:

```
     $treeObject = Doctrine_Core::getTable('EszkozKategoria')->getTree();
           $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('e.megnevezes')
                ->from('EszkozKategoria e')
                ->where('megnevezes LIKE "%fúró%"');
            $treeObject->setBaseQuery($q);
            $tree = $treeObject->fetchTree();
            $treeObject->resetBaseQuery();
            $query = $treeObject->getBaseQuery();
            $query->setHydrationMode(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY_HIERARCHY);
            $treeObject->setBaseQuery($query);

            foreach ($tree as $node) {
                //$treeObject2 = Doctrine_Core::getTable('EszkozKategoria')->getTree();
                //$tmp = $treeObject2->fetchBranch($node->id, array('depth' => 3), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY_HIERARCHY);
                //var_dump($tmp);
                //echo $node->getNode()->getPath(' / ', true) . "\n";
                $a = $node->getNode()->getAncestors();
                var_dump($a);
            }
```

I  want the node(s), and all ancestors.

Comment: What is your code basis? What have you tried so far? Do you have difficulties setting up the "Nested Set" or just want to know how to query the database?

Comment: @DrColossos: I have problem only how to search in rthe nested set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would so:

```
$listLeaf = FokonyviKategoriaTable::getInstance()->createQuery()
    ->where('level = ?', 2) //all leaf
    ->fetchArray();
$list = array();
foreach ($listLeaf as $id => $node) {
    $list[$node['id']] = $nade['megnevezes'];
    $list['ancestors'] = $node->getNode()->getAncestors();
}
return $list;
```